Clearing a matplotlib graph for new input to generate Collate sequence
Hobbyist programmer here. I wrote a program in Python using a tkinter GUI and matplotlib to  calculate and plot a Collatz conjecture sequence generated from a number input by a user:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
NavigationToolbar2Tk)


seq =[]

def calc():
    global num
    num = int(entry.get())

    while num > 2:
        if num % 2 == 0:
         num = num / 2

        else:
            num = 3 * num + 1

        seq.append(int(num))
    

def plot_sequence():

    global ax
    global canvas

    fig = Figure(facecolor='lightblue', edgecolor = "blue")
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(seq, marker='o', linestyle='-')
    ax.set_xlabel('Iteration')
    ax.set_ylabel('Value')
    ax.set_title('Collatz Sequence')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    
    ax.plot(seq)

def clear_graph():

    ax.clear()
    canvas.draw()
    entry.delete(0, 'end')
    seq.clear()

# def seq_display():
#     print(seq)
#     print(f"The length of the sequence generated is: {len(seq)}")



######################################################
# Create main window

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Collatz Sequence")
root.geometry("500x500")
style = ttk.Style("litera")

# Title
title_label = ttk.Label(root,
    text = "Collatz Sequence Generator",
    font = "Calibri 24",
    foreground = "#4a7e9e")
title_label.pack(pady =10)

# Input
entry_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
entry_frame.pack()

entry_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text = "Enter a Number:",
    font = "Calibri 16")
entry_label.pack(side = "left", padx = 30, pady = 30)

entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, width = 5)
entry.delete(0, 'end')
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack(side = "left", pady = 30)


entry_button = ttk.Button(entry_frame,text = "SUBMIT", command=lambda: [calc(), plot_sequence()])
entry_button.pack(side = "left", padx = 60, pady = 30)


clear_button = ttk.Button(root,text = "CLEAR", command=clear_graph)
clear_button.pack(side = "bottom", pady = 50)


root.mainloop()

Everything works fine except that when I clear the input field, sequence list and plot, and I input a new number, the plot does not generate again. I have to close the program and open it again to work. I know the sequence gets calculated again and appended back into the newly emptied sequence list (seq[]) but the plot figure stays empty when I run the program again.
I literally spent the entire day yesterday trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I modelled my "def clear_graph():" function on examples that work perfectly but in my code, it simply doesn't work. It clears, but like I said, it doesn't plot a new sequence from a new number input
If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it.
Andre

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

you could create Figure() and FigureCanvasTkAgg() only once.

inside () don't use spaces around = - see more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

using [] in lambda only to execute two functions is not preferred. See more PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

Code works for me when I create Figure and Canvas only once.
Maybe it was creating new Canvas on top of old Canvas but it was changing plot on old Canvas.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

# --- functions ---

def calc():
    #seq.clear()
    
    num = int(entry.get())

    while num > 2:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num / 2
        else:
            num = 3 * num + 1
        seq.append(int(num))
    
def plot_sequence():
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(seq, marker="o", linestyle="-")
    ax.plot(seq)
    canvas.draw()
    
def create_graph():
    calc()
    plot_sequence()
    
def clear_graph():
    ax.clear()
    canvas.draw()
    entry.delete(0, "end")
    seq.clear()

# def seq_display():
#     print(seq)
#     print(f"The length of the sequence generated is: {len(seq)}")

# --- main ---

seq = []

# Create main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Collatz Sequence")
root.geometry("500x500")
#style = ttk.Style("litera")

# Title
title_label = ttk.Label(root,
    text="Collatz Sequence Generator",
    font="Calibri 24",
    foreground="#4a7e9e")
title_label.pack(pady=10)

# Input
entry_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
entry_frame.pack()

entry_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text= "Enter a Number:", font="Calibri 16")
entry_label.pack(side="left", padx=30, pady=30)

entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, width=5)
#entry.delete(0, "end")   # no need it at start
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack(side="left", pady=30)

entry_button = ttk.Button(entry_frame, text="SUBMIT", command=create_graph)
entry_button.pack(side="left", padx=60, pady=30)

clear_button = ttk.Button(root, text="CLEAR", command=clear_graph)
clear_button.pack(side="bottom", pady=50)

# Figure and Canvas
fig = Figure(facecolor="lightblue", edgecolor="blue")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xlabel("Iteration")
ax.set_ylabel("Value")
ax.set_title("Collatz Sequence")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=1)

root.mainloop()

